# How to compare two tables,if no match insert those values to a table which doesn't have data?

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

I need to compare two tables `Main_Table` and `OUT-Table`, `OUT_Table` contains data but `Main_Table` may not have all the data..so I need to compare these tables if no match then just insert these unmatched values to `Main_Table`. This is my query...

```
Insert into Main_Table MT (MT.SerialNo) values (Select SerialNo 
from Main_Table MT where not exists (select SerialNo from OUT_Table OT 
where OT.SerialNo = MT.SerialNo))
```

This is selecting the values from `out_Table` which are not in `Main_Table` but not Inserting the values into main_table. I'am using Oracle database, Java(JSP). Please help me out to do this.

Comment: `INSERT ... SELECT ...` doesn't take `VALUES` try removing it

Comment: doesn't sound like a brilliant design
but i think u need to remove 'values'

Comment: I am getting NullPointerException if I remove values.

Answer (score 2):

```
Insert into Main_Table MT (MT.SerialNo)  
values ( Select SerialNo 
         from Main_Table MT 
         where not exists ( select SerialNo 
                            from OUT_Table OT 
                            where OT.SerialNo = MT.SerialNo
                          )
       )
```

The `INSERT INTO..SELECT FROM` syntax that you've used here isn't correct, the `values` keyword is not required here. Should be just

```
Insert into Main_Table MT (MT.SerialNo)  
( Select SerialNo 
         from Main_Table MT 
         where not exists ( select SerialNo 
                            from OUT_Table OT 
                            where OT.SerialNo = MT.SerialNo
                          )
 )
```

Here's an example [that Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2126076) provides.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick reply. Will try this.

Comment: @sailaja if it is working it wouldn't hurt to accept the answer.